# Android development virtual device speed

Tags: android, mobile

I am new in Android development field. I made my first application in Android application Hello world. when I run the project it takes to much time to load Android Virtual Device. is there any way to compile and run android application fast like visual studio? 
Please suggest a good answer.

Comment: The first thing I started with was a faster computer. ;-)

Comment: use good processor with good RAM...

Comment: FYI, Android itself is OS and if you run AVD, that means you have started 2nd OS on XP/Linux/iOS so your machine configuration matters a lot.

Comment: I worked with MSVS and used the windows mobile emulator .. its not that big difference. It depends on your hardware (PC). so get better CPU,RAM ..

Comment: You can keep the emulator running once you've started it. That way you won't have to wait for it to start up every time you want to test your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Virtual Device is slow, you need to use a faster computer.
According to me the best option is to use a mobile device to test your application. It works faster in comparison to the virtual device.

Comment: how much system configuration u will suggest...

Comment: my laptop is core i3 dell isprion with 2 gb ram...

Comment: Well I would suggest you to upgrade RAM of your system. But if you have a android device I would suggest you to use that for testing.

Answer (score 0):

No. as far as I know, possibility is less but if you open the virtual device once and then keep it open, the application would not take much time when you run the application again.

Also, you can try running app in your mobile phone - 
[Have a look here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)